# Linux Terminal Two Conditions to check

Tags: linux, bash

I need to check if node is running and if file /root/app/application.js exists and return corresponding message in terminal...

For checking if node is running or not i do this and this works:

```
if [ $(pgrep node | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo "node is not running..."; else echo "node is running"; fi
```

Now i need to add to this to check also if file not exists /root/app/application.js so i found that this command is what i need:

```
if [ ! -f /root/app/application.js ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
fi
```

I try to add this two commands in one with the following code:

```
if [ $(pgrep node | wc -l) -eq 0 || ! -f /root/app/application.js]; then echo "node is not running..."; else echo "node is running"; fi
```

But i get error `-bash: [: missing`]'`

So how to combine two commands that check if node is running and if file not exists into one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ $(pgrep node | wc -l) -eq 0 -o ! -f /root/app/application.js ]; then echo "node is not running..."; else echo "node is running"; fi
```

If you need logical "or" in bash, you must use `-o` key. (Also, `-a` key if you need logical "and")